# discord oauth2 access token api php returns "invalid user"

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, discord

my project wants to authorize a user through Discord Api, user logs in to my project then redirected to discord authorization page that authorization renders a code and after that I need to get access token from code through token uri mention in [Discord Developer Source](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#shared-resources), my code to access token is this:

```
$authorization = base64_encode("OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID:OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET");
$header = array("Authorization: Basic {$authorization}", "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
$content = "grant_type=authorization_code&code=$authorization_code&redirect_uri=$redirectURI";

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $tokenURL,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $content
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

it returns

```
{"error": "invalid_client"}
```

i checked same error was posted in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55391068/discord-oauth2-receiving-invalid-client-error), which suggests to put `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in header, my function is already doing it, I am using Discord for first time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with the output of `$authorization`? Do you have to write `Basic` as a prefix?

Comment: @AlexioVay I tried it without Basic and its rendering the same result

Comment: @MagnusEriksson its working now thanks, I put client id and secrete id in content instead of headers.